# How to check if list contains needed rows using javascript in sharepoint2010?

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint

I have calendar list called Events and custom list called Attendees.
On default display form of Events there are "registration on event" button with javascript that creates record in Attendees list like:
"EventID" and "AttendeeName"/

```js
var siteUrl = '/hr/events';
var eventID = Utilities.SPForm.getParameterValue('ID');

var thisUserID = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser();


function RegNewAttendee() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Attendees');
 
    var objUsers = new Array();
    objUsers.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(thisUserID));
   
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
       
    oListItem.set_item('EventID', eventID);
    oListItem.set_item('Attendee', objUsers);
          
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
        
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Registration complete! (' + thisUserID + ')');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

How can I check before posting if there alredy exist row in Attendees list with current eventID and Name, so I can avoid duplicate of registration info?
Also this is needed to find and delete this row when user wants to cancel his registration.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want to do is compose a CAML query that filters on the desired Name and eventID, and query the list for matching items.

In the callback method for that asynchronous query, set a variable to false. Then, when you iterate through the returned items, set the variable to true to indicate that a matching item already exists. You can then decide whether to create the item based on the value of that variable.

This means you'll be doing up to two calls to `clientContext.executeQueryAsync()`: the first query is to check whether the item already exists, the second is to create the item.